# Azure DevOps Pipeline Deployment to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, azure, deployment, devops

I have a requirement of Azure DevOps to automate deployment to Azure PostgreSQL DB. I can find the Task for Azure SQL Database, but not for PostgreSQL.

Is there some Extensions or Plugins , or such things, which is needed for the Task.
Or how to find the Task.

DB - Azure Database for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no task yet in AzureDevOps pipelines to deploy to Azure Database for PostgreSQL. 
However some customers are using Entity Framework migrations to accomplish the same. 

One such example is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387662/updating-postgresql-db-through-efcore-migrations-in-azure-devops

Hope you find it useful

Comment: Have you tried YUNIQL. Seems, with this, it can be doable.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. You could add this comment as an answer instead.

Comment: Haha !! Still strugling, I got  a way, but there are lot to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I got a way using [YUNIQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rdagumampan.yuniql-azdevops-extensions).

You will find this plugin in Studio and it is configurable for PostgreSQL. You have to follow the [documentation](https://yuniql.io/docs/migrate-via-azure-devops-pipelines/).